# SQL Server2016 Linked Server>>A transport-level error has occurred...provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - The pipe has been ended

Tags: sql-server, odbc, simba

I setup a linked server with Simba ODBC Driver using SQL Server 2016 linked server and the connection is successful. I can execute the queries but sometimes 
the SQL Server service/Agent crashes(not running), and no results are returned for the query.I get the following error message:

> Msg 109, Level 20, State 0, Line 0 A transport-level error has
>   occurred when receiving results from the server.  (provider: Shared
>   Memory Provider, error: 0 - The pipe has been ended.)

**System Environment**

Window Server 2016 (64bit)

MS SQL Server 2016

MS SQL Server Management studio 2017 (v17.2)

In SQL Server Error Log, I get following error message as below

**SQL SERVER ERROR LOG**

path : D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG

2018-10-11 08:39:44.36 Server      Error: 17311, Severity: 16, State: 1.

2018-10-11 08:39:44.36 Server      SQL Server is terminating because of fatal exception c0000005. This error may be caused by an unhandled Win32 or C++ exception, or by an access violation encountered during exception handling. Check the SQL error log for any related stack dumps or messages. This exception forces SQL Server to shutdown. To recover from this error, restart the server (unless SQLAgent is configured to auto restart).

2018-10-11 08:39:44.38 Server      **Dump thread - spid = 0, EC = 0x0000000000000000

2018-10-11 08:39:44.38 Server      ***Stack Dump being sent to D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0005.txt

2018-10-11 08:39:44.38 Server      * *******************************************************************************

2018-10-11 08:39:44.38 Server      *

2018-10-11 08:39:44.38 Server      * BEGIN STACK DUMP:

2018-10-11 08:39:44.38 Server      *   10/11/18 08:39:44 spid 6160

2018-10-11 08:39:44.38 Server      *

2018-10-11 08:39:44.38 Server      * ex_handle_except encountered exception C0000005 - Server terminating

Could anyone please help to suggest the way to solve this issue? 
How can I solve this issue??

Thank you so much.

Comment: If the server is crashing, that's why you're getting the error. We need to know the error for the server crashing, not the response from the application when it's running the SQL (you can't expect results from a SQL Server if it crashed while performing the operation). The error will be in the Server's logs.

Comment: SQL server error log as above. Please help to suggest me. Thank you.

Comment: And the mentioned stack dump?

Comment: Can you help me analyze stack dump?
I have uploaded all sql server error log/dump file to link below 
https://files.fm/u/fz68geeg
(Let me know if it is inaccessible.)

Please advise...

Thanks.